# Change order of items in ggplot2 legend with combined items

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `ggplot2` to draw a scatter plot which contains both a grouped and an ungrouped `geom_smooth()`. I would like the entry for the ungrouped smooth to appear at the top or bottom of the legend, but the legend is sorted alphabetically instead.

```
my.colors <- c('4' = 'red', 'f' = 'green', 'r' = 'blue', 'all' = 'black')
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = drv), alpha = 1/3) + theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = drv), method = 'lm') +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = 'all'), method = 'lm') +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Drive Types", values = my.colors)
```

[image: Scatterplot]

The problem is similar to [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387516/original-order-of-factor-levels-changes-in-legend-when-plotting-layers-which-use), but including a `geom_blank()` does not solve it. Also, including `'all'` as a level in `mpg$drv` makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use breaks?

```
my.colors <- c('4' = 'red', 'f' = 'green', 'r' = 'blue', 'all' = 'black')
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = drv), alpha = 1/3) + theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = drv), method = 'lm') +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = 'all'), method = 'lm') +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Drive Types", values = my.colors, 
                     breaks=c("all", "4", "f", "r"))
```

Comment: This answered a similar question I had, which was, "What if I only want to show some of the legend?" In this example, `breaks = c("all", "r")` was what I needed.